# Disable mouse right click event for GridView on WinRT C# app

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, right-click

i have a GridView in my WinRT app, the problem is that one of the standard functionality of the gridViwes is when you click the right button (MOUSE), the item clicked is selected, 
this will focus on this item , and loos focus from the previous one, 
i wont this to happen, and i need to disable the right click mouse 
- i think that this is the solution ,,, 
- but if you think that desabling Right mouse click event, is a wrong avtion ,, 
please give me other suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the best solution for this, and I really don't know WinRT's GridView but I'm a Silverlight developer so I think you can subscribe to MouseRightButtunUp/Down events of the cells and handle them with `e.Handled = true;` in the code-behind.

For WinRT(Edit):

```
    private void Target_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     if (ptr.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
     {
        Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(Target);
        if (ptrPt.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
        e.Handled = true;
        }
     }
    }
```

Hope this one helps!

Comment: the MouseRightButtonUP/DOWN does not exist in WINRT :/

Comment: Yes you are right. Because it made for tablets too! It has a pointerpressed event instead. I'm editing my post according to this.